# Component stuck on rendering when number of thread for rendering increased to more then 1

Tags: web8, publishing

We are using SDL web8 While increasing number of thread to more then 1 for publishing the components are getting stuck inside publishing queue on rendering phase. Inside component template(c# Compound Template) we are fetching data from external oracle database and prepare html to display. should we need to modify our component template to handle multiple thread or i m missing some configuration.

**Update :**

After rebuilding index of external database rendering become faster and components are getting publish but publisher service taking long time in resolving components as such i m not using any custom resolver.

Comment: I guess it really depends on the logic your executing. If all components are querying for the same data then there could be something in your code locking the records? You could try attaching to the tcmpublisher and debugging?

Comment: Don't forget to check the Event Viewer too, maybe your query throws an error / connectionstring is incorrect or something like that. If you are not able to do some remote debugging then use Template Builder and add more logging inside your template.

Comment: @NunoLinhares Just to elaborate on the above issue, it may be worth mentioning that we have 2 CMS servers configured in High Availability and both have the publisher running.

Comment: @NunoLinhares After rebuilding index of external database and increasing workersize to 40 and worker to 20 in deployer config and increasing thread for rendering and deployment to 4 the components are publishing successfully but components are taking too much time on resolving state around 2 min for 4 components.is there any way to reduce resolving time.we are not using any custom resolver.